# Content script pattern matching

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm looking for a way to match certain patterns on a url path that should invoke the content script of my Chrome extension. I've read through the [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) documentation, however I cannot find how to match the following scenarios:

```
http://mypage.com/some/sub/path - should match
http://mypage.com/some/sub/     - should not match
```

where as *path* can be anything.. I tried with the pattern

```
http://mypage.com/some/sub/*
```

but this also seems to cover *http://mypage.com/some/sub/*

Is there any way to use regular expressions for pattern matching? The rule should be: **Match any url that starts with http://mypage.com/some/sub/ followed by atleast a single character**

Comment: Have you tried `http://mypage.com/some/sub/+`?

Comment: The regex for that url followed by any character would be /http\:\/\/mypage\.com\/some\/sub\/./

Comment: @ackerman It's not a regex, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Solution is `"exclude_matches"` as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs).

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://mypage.com/some/sub/*"],
    "exclude_matches": ["http://mypage.com/some/sub/"],
    "js": ["myscript.js"]
  }
],
```